# How do I specify an extent to my map without disabling zooming in?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, extents

I'm a bit new to GIS in general so apologies for the newbish question but in ArcGIS 10 I'm trying to get it so my map is only for my local city government (where all my data is) and a small surrounding area. I'd like to have it set up so that by dragging the scroll bars I'm confined to that area instead of the current scrolling around the entire earth. It renders the scroll bars useless besides a quick arrow nudge here or there. I've tried different extent settings on my data frame from [this page from ESRI](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000011000000.htm) to no avail. I want to still be able to zoom in to inspect features closer but all viewing extent settings seem to disable zooming in and out. Is my base map causing a problem since it's worldwide imagery? All my other data is confined to my city and some small surrounding area. Am I out of luck in doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spatial Bookmarks  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000043s000000

Comment: Spatial Bookmarks have certainly helped but panning and zooming are still quite unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you looked at that from the ESRI link you posted.  That link only focuses on the Extent portion of that dialog tab.  Do you get what you want if you...

- Zoom to the extent you want
- Open the Data Frame Properties (View-->Data Fram Properties) and select the Data Frame tab
- In the middle of the dialog box is the 'Extent Used By Full Extent Command'...select the 'Other' option and click the 'Specifiy Extent' box
- Select the 'Current Visible Extent' option and OK your way back out of all dialogs

Comment: That's almost perfect! After I did that I clicked on full extent and now it always goes to the view I want. The scroll bars resize to an appropriate size for that area. Unfortunately if I zoom out a bit too much or pan too far I can easily lose my data. The scroll bars dynamically resize in reference to my current view.

Is there no way to define the maximum extent of your map that I don't wish to pan past, zoom out from, without also disabling zooming in as well?

Comment: If you 'lose' your data, why wouldn't using the Full Extent or Zoom Previous buttons be acceptable?  You might be able to engineer some sort of solution, but that's a lot of effort to save yourself 1 or 2 mouseclicks.  If you have specific areas you need to target on a regular basis, I'd use Mapperz suggestion above of the Bookmarks function to quickly get you to the extents you need.

Comment: I already use bookmarks currently and I do use the Full Extent and Zoom Previous buttons but neither of these suggestions truly solves the issue of defining a maximum area to work in. I don't wish to sound ungrateful for your answers, they do help somewhat alleviate a nagging issue for me, they just aren't the exact solution I'm looking for. Am I really not able to define a separate min and max extent for my map?